# How to use Jflex and Bison Together?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, lexer, jflex

I am really struggling to use Jflex and Bison together. For example, here's some sample code:

https://github.com/valecor95/bison-flex-jflex-examples/tree/master/Java/1_BalancedParentheses/BalPar1

You run `make`:
[image]

It just makes a load of files, and then if I want to test to see if it succeeds with the parser (stuff in a file called test.txt), I just can't. It's forced to take in System.in. It's really frustrating as there's very little readable and simple documentation for JFLEX and bison.

Any advice at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your question was not "how do I take input from a file?", which was the only specific question I could find in your post, please ask a new, more clearly focused question. A question of the form "how do I use [some large software package]" is far too broad for StackOverflow, since it requires a book-length answer. And there are books. Or at least the manual, in the case of JFlex. Some proficiency in Java is probably necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In BalPar.y line 15, right at the beginning of main, it instantiates a BalParLexer with `System.in` as its input stream. You could add a few lines of code to check for a command line argument and use it as the name of a file to open instead of System.in.

That's all pretty well independent of Bison and JFkex.